# How can I cache data that I already requested and access it from the store using React and Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How can I get data from the store using React Redux Toolkit and get a cached version if I already requested it?

I need to request multiple users for example user1, user2, and user3. If I make a request for user1 after it has already been requested then I do not want to fetch user1 from the API again.  Instead it should give me the info of the user1 from the store.

How can I do this in React with a Redux Toolkit slice?

Comment: You need to have separate operations for request (useDispatch) and retrieve (useSelector).  Inside your request you can see if the user is already loaded and cancel: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-before-execution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit**: This answer predates the release of [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) which has made this task much easier!  RTK Query automatically handles caching and much more.  Check out the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries) for how to set it up.

Keep reading if you are interested in understanding more about some of the concepts at play.

---

#### Tools

Redux Toolkit can help with this but we need to combine various "tools" in the toolkit.

- [createEntityAdapter](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) allows us to store and select entities like a user object in a structured way based on a unique ID.
- [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) will create the thunk action that fetches data from the API.
- [createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) or [createReducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer) creates our reducer.

#### React vs. Redux

We are going to create a `useUser` custom React hook to load a user by id.

We will need to use separate hooks in our hooks/components for reading the data (`useSelector`) and initiating a fetch (`useDispatch`).  Storing the user state will always be the job of Redux.  Beyond that, there is some leeway in terms of whether we handle certain logic in React or in Redux.

We could look at the selected value of `user` in the custom hook and only `dispatch` the `requestUser` action if `user` is `undefined`.  Or we could `dispatch` `requestUser` all the time and have the `requestUser` thunk check to see if it needs to do the fetch using the [`condition` setting of `createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-before-execution).

#### Basic Approach

Our naïve approach just checks if the user already exists in the state.  We don't know if any other requests for this user are already pending.

Let's assume that you have some function which takes an id and fetches the user:

```
const fetchUser = async (userId) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`);
    return res.data;
};
```

We create a `userAdapter` helper:

```
const userAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

// needs to know the location of this slice in the state
export const userSelectors = userAdapter.getSelectors((state) => state.users);

export const { selectById: selectUserById } = userSelectors;
```

We create a `requestUser` thunk action creator that only executes the fetch if the user is not already loaded:

```
export const requestUser = createAsyncThunk("user/fetchById", 
  // call some API function
  async (userId) => {
    return await fetchUser(userId);
  }, {
    // return false to cancel
    condition: (userId, { getState }) => {
        const existing = selectUserById(getState(), userId);
        return !existing;
    }
  }
);
```

We can use `createSlice` to create the reducer.  The `userAdapter` helps us update the state.

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "users",
    initialState: userAdapter.getInitialState(),
    reducers: {
    // we don't need this, but you could add other actions here
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(requestUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            userAdapter.upsertOne(state, action.payload);
        });
    }
});
export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
```

But since our `reducers` property is empty, we could just as well use `createReducer`:

```
export const userReducer = createReducer(
    userAdapter.getInitialState(),
    (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(requestUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            userAdapter.upsertOne(state, action.payload);
        });
    }
)
```

Our React hook returns the value from the selector, but also triggers a `dispatch` with a `useEffect`:

```
export const useUser = (userId: EntityId): User | undefined => {
  // initiate the fetch inside a useEffect
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      dispatch(requestUser(userId));
    },
    // runs once per hook or if userId changes
    [dispatch, userId]
  );

  // get the value from the selector
  return useSelector((state) => selectUserById(state, userId));
};
```

#### isLoading

The previous approach ignored the fetch if the user was already *loaded*, but what about if it is already *loading*?  We could have multiple fetches for the same user occurring simultaneously.

Our state needs to store the fetch status of each user in order to fix this problem.  In the [docs example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-before-execution) we can see that they store a keyed object of statuses alongside the user entities (you could also store the status as part of the entity).

We need to add an empty `status` dictionary as a property on our `initialState`:

```
const initialState = {
  ...userAdapter.getInitialState(),
  status: {}
};
```

We need to update the status in response to all three `requestUser` actions.  We can get the `userId` that the thunk was called with by looking at the [`meta.arg`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions) property of the `action`:

```
export const userReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(requestUser.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.status[action.meta.arg] = 'pending';
    });
    builder.addCase(requestUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status[action.meta.arg] = 'fulfilled';
      userAdapter.upsertOne(state, action.payload);
    });
    builder.addCase(requestUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status[action.meta.arg] = 'rejected';
    });
  }
);
```

We can select a status from the state by id:

```
export const selectUserStatusById = (state, userId) => state.users.status[userId];
```

Our thunk should look at the status when determining if it should fetch from the API.  We do not want to load if it is already `'pending'` or `'fulfilled'`. We will load if it is `'rejected'` or `undefined`:

```
export const requestUser = createAsyncThunk("user/fetchById", 
    // call some API function
    async (userId) => {
        return await fetchUser(userId);
    }, {
        // return false to cancel
        condition: (userId, { getState }) => {
            const status = selectUserStatusById(getState(), userId);
            return status !== "fulfilled" && status !== "pending";
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Great answer, it handles all use cases I was thinking about. thank you!

Comment: @YassinAjdi this answer is a bit "dated" -- you should check out the Redux Toolkit "RTK Query" package which handles all of this automatically!

Comment: @LindaPaiste While RTK Query is indeed an awesome tool, it's not the tool for every scenario and thus your answer is still very relevant.