# Refreshing page gives 'Page not found'. (React BrowserRouter)

Tags: react-redux, react-router, reddit

I built a simple reddit app with React-Redux and when I go to a post page like /posts/mlxft5 and refresh the page it says that the post is not found. I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bird-mymko?file=/src/App.js) on codesandbox.
here's my app.js code

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router > 
      <div className="App">
      <div className="App-navbar">
        <SubredditsList />
      </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route  exact path="/" component={StartMessage}/>
          <Route  exact path="/search" component={SearchPostsList}/>
          <Route exact path="/posts" component={PostsList} />
          <Route  path="/posts/:postId" component={PostDetailRender}/>
          <Route  path="/search/:postId" component={SingleSearchPostRender}/>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App`
```

Comment: Do you mean that if you load/reload [this](https://mymko.csb.app/posts/mk6763) you get `Post not found!`?

Comment: If that is the problem then you should dispatch getting the post by id somewhere in [this file](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bird-mymko?file=/src/features/posts/singlePost.js). If you worried you fetch multiple times then don't fetch if you have the post in state (re use the selector in your thunk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are only requesting posts from the API when we are on the `/posts` page for a subreddit.  There are no requests initiated by `/posts/mlxft`.  We need to add an additional thunk action that can fetch and store a single post from the id.

We don't want to fetch posts that are already in Redux when we click on a single post from the list on the `/posts` page. We we will use the [`condition` setting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-before-execution) of the `createAsyncThunk` function to conditionally cancel the fetch if the data already exists.

```
export const fetchSinglePost = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/fetchSingle",
  async (postId) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.reddit.com/api/info/?id=t3_${postId}`
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    return json.data.children[0].data;
  },
  {
    condition: (postId, { getState }) => {
      const { posts } = getState();
      if (posts.entities[postId]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

You need to add additional cases in your reducer to handle this thunk.  Note: if you use [builder callback notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-builder-callback-notation) instead of reducer map object notation then you could combine your two "rejected" cases.

```
[fetchSinglePost.pending]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "loading";
},
[fetchSinglePost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "succeeded";
  postsAdapter.upsertOne(state, action.payload);
},
[fetchSinglePost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "failed";
  state.error = action.error.message;
}
```

Inside of your `PostDetailRender` component you need to `dispatch` the `fetchSinglePost` action.  It's ok to dispatch it all cases because the thunk itself will cancel the fetching.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchSinglePost(postId));
}, [dispatch, postId]);
```

You could potentially have a `status` for each post rather than one for the whole slice.  I explain how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968631/how-can-i-cache-data-that-i-already-requested-and-access-it-from-the-store-using/66977741#66977741).

[Updated CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kowalevski-6kg00?file=/src/features/posts/postsSlice.js:2064-2430)

I also made some changes so that you don't fetch the same subreddit's posts more than once.

Comment: Linda, you are amazing! I learned a lot thanks to you! I was thinking that if I use `match` then I can just grab a post from the posts list and it would work even when refreshing the page, but now I see that I still need to fetch and store a single post from the id.

Comment: FYI when you navigate with react-router-dom the Redux store stays loaded but when you refresh the page it resets the Redux state.

Comment: It workes perfectly on my localhost:3000 now, but still does the same thing when I deploy it with Netlify. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  Is it the "Post not found" message, or you can't load the page at all?  If you can't load it all then you need to change some server settings to allow multiple access points for your app.

Comment: Yeah, can't load it at all. Will try to find some information about the server settings then, thanks again!

Comment: I just needed to change one line in package.json to -  "homepage": "https://minireddit.netlify.app/" and it's all fixed!